# Как скопировать текст при нажатии кнопки мыши?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Например, есть на странице адрес эл.почты `test@mail.ru`. При нажатии на email его надо перенести в буфер обмена. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Так пробовали? https://habrahabr.ru/post/256027/

Answer (score 5):

```js
document.querySelector('a').onclick = function(e){
  if (document.selection) {
      const range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(this);
      range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
      const range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNode(this);
      window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  }
  document.execCommand('copy');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href='javascript:;'>copypatse</a>
```

Comment: А как потом вывести "текст скопирован в буфер обмена"?

Comment: `alert("текст скопирован в буфер обмена")`, `console.log("текст скопирован в буфер обмена")`, `someelement.innerText = "текст скопирован в буфер обмена";` + еще сотни способов показать этот текст в DOM

Comment: При нажатии на ссылку перезагружается страница. Как сделать это без перезагрузки?

Comment: @StepanIvanov Обновил ответ